# Is there any way of changing parameters of websocket without ending connection?

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, graphql, apollo

My app has coin infos in its table view cell which has 40 cell. I have faced a problem by connecting to the server via websocket. It has been updated its every cell on the tableview continuously therefore in my opinion it hasn't become a useful method to me because of my future plans of adding much more coins to the app which can turn in to be a bigger problem for me in the future. I would like to update the coins which are on the screen but not the ones which are not on the screen. In other words, I would like to update parameters of websocket without end connection. I searched for the graphQL subscription system but I'm not sure about the system which would it be helpful. What are your suggestions for me?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "parameters"? Do you mean like query parameters on the socket's URL? If so, then it sounds like you'd want to change your websocket to be more generic, then pass the parameters over the websocket itself, or something along those lines.

Comment: Sorry I used wrong word. I mean this ["action" : "SubAdd","subs": trades] as parameters (trades is the string array which trade symbols found). When the connection starts I send this json object via socket.write() command. Can I change that field without restarting the connection? Because as I mentioned at the post I don't want to fetch unnecessary coin infos. What do you think about graphQL subscription?

Comment: I don't think I can answer the question about restarting the connection, it's really depends specifically on the API you're working with. GraphQL subscriptions are fine, but if you already having a Websocket protocol that _isn't_ GraphQL, switching to it just for this sounds like overkill when you could adjust the protocol you already have.